# Disable selection after an array has reached a limit

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a [HTagView](https://github.com/popodidi/HTagView) library to display a list of tags. I have populated the tags and now I want to limit the selection of up to 3. Here is where I'm attempting this:

```
var selectedInterests = [Int]()

func tagView(_ tagView: HTagView, tagSelectionDidChange selectedIndices: [Int]) {

    selectedInterests.removeAll()

    for i in selectedIndices {
        selectedInterests.append(i)

        if selectedInterests.count > 3 {
            print("limit reached")
            selectedInterests.removeLast()
            tagView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I've attempted to remove the last item of the array but this also doesn't work. Most examples are showing this example based on the indexPath of a table or collectionView. How do I achieve it with out either of the two?

Comment: I don't understand what you need to achieve, you need only show 3 items? its that what you need?

Comment: No, I am trying to perform an action after the limit has been reached. I want to disable anymore selections. But only showing 3 would also be good too!

Comment: then you should break the cycle and reload the tagView after that instead of reload continuously in the cycle, try that and let me know

Comment: So I've put the `reloadData()` outside the loop but nothing changes still.

Comment: check my answer, and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to immediately deselect the tag if the amount of already selected tags is greater than 3. I would also make the amount as a variable that you can easily change the value of:

```
var maxTagsSelected = 3

func tagView(_ tagView: HTagView, tagSelectionDidChange selectedIndices: [Int]) {
    if selectedIndices.count > maxTagsSelected {
        tagView.deselectTagAtIndex(selectedIndices[maxTagsSelected])
    }
}
```

The variable maxTagsSelected will always be the index of the last element in selectedIndices.

Comment: I get this error 'Ambiguous subscript with base type '[Int]' and index type 'CountableRange<Int>'' when trying your code.

Comment: @mninety5 Sorry, I forgot to wrap it into the Array initializer. I've updated the code, please try it now.

Comment: Is this code suppose to limit the selection to 3? Because your code still let's me add more. Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: does it copy all elements from selectedIndices?

Comment: It's continually selecting. And sorry I am not completely sure as this is new method for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159755/discussion-between-mninety5-and-ruslan-serebriakov).

Comment: Quick one, when I add a counter, and select 4 it only selects 3 but counts up to 4 when it shouldn't  which means it it still taking in 4 in the array :/

Comment: Use this: counterLbl.text = "(tagView.selectedIndices.count) out of 3"

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
var selectedInterests = [Int]()

func tagView(_ tagView: HTagView, tagSelectionDidChange selectedIndices: [Int]) {

    selectedInterests.removeAll()
    selectedInterests = selectedIndices[0..<3]

}
```